# Using JSON builder how do I stuff a Map into each Object of Object Array

Tags: grails, groovy

Given: `myList = [request:request,actions:actions]` where request is an object and actions is a map.
Trying to get something like this:

```
{data:[
   {a:'a',b:'b',actions:[c:'c',d:'d']},..
  ]}
```

where a and b are request properties while c and d are actions are map entries.
using:

```
render(contentType:"text/json"){
    data = array {
       myList.each { obj->
          rqst = {
             obj.request
             actions = {actions: obj.actions}
          }
       }
    }
}
```

obviously syntax here is wrong... but perhaps close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following accomplishes what you were looking for.  PropsHolder is a simple inner class with two (a, b) properties

```
def request = new PropsHolder()
request.a = "a"
request.b = "b"
def actions = [c: "c", d: "d"]

def myList = [request: request, actions: actions]

render(contentType:"text/json")
{
    [data: [
    a: myList.request.a,
    b: myList.request.b,
    actions: myList.actions
    ]
    ]
}
```

The json result looks like this when output to a web page:

```
{"data":{"a":"a","b":"b","actions":{"c":"c","d":"d"}}}
```

I wasn't quite sure with the [a, b, actions] collection if you were looking for a map or an array.  Tough to tell from the output, I went with map.

Comment: Thanks Bill, it is possible to do however I did not want to list out all of the properties of the request object (too many). I was looking for something more graceful. AFAIK there really isn't a way to do that except for using an Expando class where you can stuff properties on the fly.

Comment: Yeah I debated adding code that iterated the properties of request but it would have been more code to pull out the properties you wouldn't want than to hard code the a and b references.  If you have a lot of properties obviously it would be worth it.